# How to encode string as unicode in julia?

Tags: json, julia

when we use JSON.json(Dict("text"=>"我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体"))

we got this:  {"text":"我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体"}

but what we want might be:

{"text":"\u6211\u80fd\u541e\u4e0b\u73bb\u7483\u800c\u4e0d\u4f24\u8eab\u4f53"}

not found how to do this in pkg JSON or Unicode...

```
julia> json(

json(a) in JSON.Writer at /home/user/.julia/packages/JSON/ebvl3/src/Writer.jl:354

json(a, indent) in JSON.Writer at /home/user/.julia/packages/JSON/ebvl3/src/Writer.jl:355
```

Comment: there used to be a function [char](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/issues/73) , but seems unavailable in v1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
julia> s2u(s::AbstractString) = join(["\\u"*string(Int(c), base=16, pad=4) for c in s])
s2u (generic function with 1 method)

julia> s2u("我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体")
"\\u6211\\u80fd\\u541e\\u4e0b\\u73bb\\u7483\\u800c\\u4e0d\\u4f24\\u8eab\\u4f53"

julia> println(s2u("我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体"))
\u6211\u80fd\u541e\u4e0b\u73bb\u7483\u800c\u4e0d\u4f24\u8eab\u4f53
```